# Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access: Failed to connect to [git domain] port 443 after xyz ms: Timed out

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, devops, vpn

I am trying to clone a repo from `Visual Studio 2017` but I am getting error as below

Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access '[repo url]': Failed to connect to [repo domain] port 443 after 21052 ms: Timed out

We have repo hosted in Azure DevOps. It worked when I cloned it using open internet but it doesn't work on VM. I am not sure if any firewall or proxy is blocking it because I am able to open link in the browser.

Comment: Is the browser also running in the VM? Remember that a virtual machine has a virtual network device connected to a virtual network, and that's most likely where the problem is: in the VM, not in Git or VS or the VPN.

Comment: @torek browser is also running on VM. Any idea if git clone uses any non-standard port that needs to be enables?

Comment: The port(s) that `git clone` uses depend on the protocol(s): http = 80, https = 443, ssh = 22, git = 9418. You can of course specify a port in your URL too.